# How can I align multirow and multicolumn equations?

Tags: equations, amsmath

There is a multiline and multirow equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
f(x)=\frac{1}{12} \cdot x \quad g(x) = \frac{1}{24} \cdot x, & x<12 \\
f(x)=1 \quad g(x) = \frac{1}{8} \cdot x - 1, & 12 \le x < 16 \\
f(x)=1 \quad g(x) = 1, & x \ge 16
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

The result is:

[image]

**What I expect is**: (align `g(x)` as well)

```
f(x)=*    g(x)=*
f(x)=*    g(x)=*
f(x)=*    g(x)=*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably need something like this (simple `cases` cannot handle this)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \left\{\begin{aligned}
      f(x)&=\tfrac{1}{12} \cdot r, & g(x) &= \tfrac{1}{24} \cdot x, & x&<12 \\
      f(x)&=1, &g(x) &= \tfrac{1}{8} \cdot x - 1, & 12 &\le x < 16 \\
      f(x)&=1, &g(x) &= 1, & x &\ge 16
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

---

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Why do u use `\tfrac` instead of `\frac`?

Comment: The fractions are the only tall things on the line. Since they are simple fractions, they are still perfectly readable in a smaller state. And thus I think it looks better. To me leaving them as `\frac` made them look pompous.